# Are specific tool related questions appropriate for SQA?

Tags: support

There does not appear to be a specific stack exchange site for questions and answers for specific testing tools (like QTP, Selenium, TestComplete, etc).  I know that the tools themselves have their own support forums and such.  However, would it be valid to ask questions about specific techniques, tasks, etc, for those tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they are testing tools, or, even if it's a person using it for testing, or another QA task, I don't see any reason why they shouldn't be asked here.

Comment: I noticed there's a Selenium2 and qtp tag already... I know once my rep is high enough I can add other tags, but would it be possible to just fill out a few more tags?  We can add TestComplete as one.  I know there are other tools out there as well (one's I'm not familiar with) but perhaps we can be a bit pro-active and just create the tags ahead of time.

Comment: In order to create the tags for them, we'd also have to ask the questions for them.  http://meta.sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/60/where-should-i-propose-tags

Answer (score 4):

Given that the Selenium StackExchange proposal got merged into this site, I can't see how testing tool questions *could* be off-topic.

Comment: The Selenium merge was the only reason why I participate in SQA site. +1

Comment: @Tarun hopefully that was the reason you came here, but it won't be the reason that you stay

Comment: @Bruce, so true - I already loving the questions on SQA site. Though I have another objective to persuade users to ask question Selenium questions on SQA site and not on Stack Overflow, but don't know how I don't know how I do that :-/

Comment: @Tarun that is a tough one